# Replace keys in values with key->values from same dictionary

Tags: python, hash-map

I have a dictionary whose values may contain keys that are already in the dictionary. What we are actually talking about are parameters. Sometimes a parameter is defined by a number plus another parameter, etc.

It looks something like this:

```
paramDict = {'ad': '2*dmcg/factor*(xw/factor)',
'dmcg': 2.05e-07,
'dxwn_3vna': 10.0,
'factor': 1,
'xw': '0+dxwn_3vna'}
```

If there is another parameter in the value it is of type string, otherwise it is an `int` or a `float`. After the replacing I want the value to be a float.

The code I wrote to solve this problem is this:

```
    for _ in range(10):
        for key, value in paramDict.items():
            if type(value) is str:
                matchList = re.findall('[a-z]\w*', value)
                matchList = [match for match in matchList if match != 'e']
                for match in matchList:
                    param = paramDict[match]
                    paramDict[key] = value.replace(match, str(param))
                try:
                    paramDict[key] = eval(paramDict[key])
                except:
                    pass
```

It works as far as I can tell, but it just doesn't feel right to just repeat the whole process a finite number of times and hope that all the strings have been replaced. Is there a safer way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me some time (the question challenged me), but after playing with some (stupidly :) ) over-complicated approaches I came up with this pretty straightforward solution. It does not even require high-end libraries

I do not think it needs explanation, but if you have questions - I will gladly answer them

**EDITED:**

It occurred to me that the original version did not handle the case when some of the expressions cannot be evaluated. Well, that may be easily  rectified.

```
def eval_dict(paramDict):
    evaluated_post_cnt = 0 # Total number of converted from previous loop
    result = {}
    while True:
        for var_name, value in paramDict.iteritems():
            if not var_name in result:
                try:
                    exec('{} = {}'.format(var_name, value))
                    result[var_name] = locals()[var_name]
                except NameError:
                    pass
        all_evaluated_num = len(result) 
        if all_evaluated_num == len(paramDict):
            # All values converted
            return result
        if evaluated_post_cnt == all_evaluated_num:
            # No new keys converted in a loop - dead end
            raise Exception('Cannot convert some keys')
        evaluated_post_cnt = all_evaluated_num
```

OK, here's the "magic":

*exec* - (not recommended by purists) attempts to execute strings as a Python command lines, so if the sting is, e.g

```
'xw =0+dxwn_3vna'
```

the execution will fail with *NameError* exception if *dxwn_3vna* has not been evaluated yet - or it will assign value *10.0* to variable with the name *xw* - as regular assignment statement. 
Assigned variable is added to local variable set - which may be accessed with function [locals()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#locals) - returns dictionary.
So, if the code succeeds in evaluating values - they are replaced in your dictionary.

That simplifies the code, because I do not have to replace variable names within strings with values - if all  variables in this string

```
2*dmcg/factor*(xw/factor)
```

are already defined, then this string may be executed

```
'ad = 2*dmcg/factor*(xw/factor)'
```

Is it clear now?

Comment: thank you very much for your answer :) although i must admit i am thoroughly puzzled... so i tried running your code and what i understand is the first time it runs through the dictionary all the Parameters that already have a numeric value get added to evaluated_keys and somehow to locals. but then during the second run through it magically computes the remaining Parameters. could you please further explain the magic that happens in the lines `exec('{} = {}'.format(var_name, value))` and `paramDict[var_name] = locals()[var_name]`?

Comment: oh and also, I am using python 2.6, so I already had to add numbers in the {} braces for `.format`, i dont know if this also affects your code in some other way!

Comment: @moringana,you may use _'%s = %s' % (var_name, str(value))_ then

Comment: yes I like it but i don't really understand it, so could you please answer my question that i asked in my first comment?

Comment: aha okay, much clearer now thank you :) that is a cool approach

Answer (score 6):

Well what you want there is evaluating expressions while keeping track
of dependencies, so you should definitely *not* implement it via regular
expressions and hoping that running it ten times is enough.

The best way in Python would probably be using the
[`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module to parse and
figure out the referenced variables, then calculate dependencies and
evaluate the parsed expressions via
[`compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile)
and [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)
while passing in the referenced variables in the `local` parameter.

That way you make sure that the expressions are actually valid, you can
use Python expressions and you can (and should) also detect cycles in
the specification.

Below is *a sketch* how to do that, not saying that is the best code,
please edit or comment with improvements, I couldn't find a good example
while searching.

```
import ast, _ast

params = {
    'ad': '2*dmcg/factor*(xw/factor)',
    'dmcg': 2.05e-07,
    'dxwn_3vna': 10.0,
    'factor': 1,
    'xw': '0+dxwn_3vna',
    'foo': 'bar',
    'bar': 'foo'
}

parsed = {}

for key, value in params.iteritems():
    parsed[key] = value

    if type(value) in (str, unicode):
        parsed[key] = ast.parse(value, mode="eval")

evaluated = {key: value for key, value in parsed.iteritems()}
```

So at this point the `evaluated` dictionary is mostly a copy of the
`params`, except that expressions have been parsed.

```
def referenced(code):
    return [node.id for node in ast.walk(code) if "id" in node._fields]
```

`referenced` returns a list with the names of referenced variables in
the expression.

```
evaluating = []

def resolve(key, value):
    if key in evaluating:
        raise Exception("Loop while evaluating {}".format(key))

    if type(value) is not _ast.Expression:
        evaluated[key] = value
        return value

    evaluating.append(key)

    locals = {name: resolve(name, evaluated[name]) for name in referenced(value)}

    result = eval(compile(value, "<unknown>", "eval"), globals(), locals)

    evaluated[key] = result

    evaluating.pop()

    return result
```

`resolve` evaluates the expression recursively but also keeps track of
the stack (in `evaluating`), so it can detect cycles by looking up the
current variable.  It also assigns the results immediately, so in
further invocations it will return early (the `not _ast.Expression`
case).

```
for key, value in parsed.iteritems():
    try:
        resolve(key, value)
    except Exception as exception:
        print ("Error while evaluating {}: {}".format(key, exception))

print(evaluated)
```

Lastly, iterate over all entries and try to evaluate them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This seems a lot more complex than my try (I've been learning Python for three weeks now), so I will first have to look into abstract syntax trees and such... When I feel like I've gotten my head around it I will get back to you :)

Comment: Yeah well, in that case this answer is overkill. If you were to use your original approach in a production setting you would run into issues though, which is why I wanted to highlight that. E.g. your solution, or @volcano's will work, but corner cases remain, which would come haunt you later on.

Comment: well the goal is indeed to make it as reliable as possible, but maybe for my case my or volcano's solution is already sufficient, I will have to check. I have already found a fault in my solution though... thank you for your answer though, I am always pleased to learn about new methods and modules!

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more robust technique than volcano's, but still less-so than ferada's, is to capture the evaluation in a fake "scope" and avoid messing with strings:

```
paramDict[var_name] = eval(value, {}, paramDict)
```

This keeps `locals` clean.

However, you don't want to start with everything available to `eval` since you'll never get a `NameError` that way. Instead, build a dictionary as you go.

What might even be better is abusing `eval`'s `locals` argument with a lazy cached evaluation strategy:

```
# from UserDict import UserDict on Python 2
from collections import UserDict

class StringScope(UserDict):
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        expr = self.data[name]

        if isinstance(expr, str):
            expr = self.data[name] = eval(expr, {}, self)

        return expr

scope = StringScope(paramDict)
```

That's it: `scope` will now lazily evaluate its values as they are requested. If you want eager evaluation, just do

```
scope = dict(StringScope(paramDict))
```

instead. This will automatically do walking of the dependency chain, too, so is technically more efficient algorithmically.

Comment: I have read up on Python OOP and am making Progress in understanding your code, however, when I try to run it I get `TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)` right in the `class StringScope(UserDict):`line. Do you have an idea about what could be the problem here? (I am using Python 2.6 and had to already change `from collections Import UserDict` to `Import UserDict` )

Comment: okay found the error, I need to write `from UserDict import UserDict`

Comment: @moringana There's already a comment on that (`# from UserDict import UserDict on Python 2`).

Comment: sorry for bothering you again, but could you explain why there are two equal signs in the line ` expr = self.data[name] = eval(expr, {}, self)`? And also, shouldn't we need to create an instance of the StringScope class before using it?

Comment: The two equals signs sets both the values. So `a = b = 0` sets `a = 0` and `b = 0`. // I am constructing an instance of the `StringScope` class (`StringScope(paramDict)`). The implicit `__getitem__` calls do the magic to make things work from there.

Comment: okay I get it now. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it! :)